# How to insert query into sql server using nodejs

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express, body-parser

I am trying to insert query into SQL Server using window authentication with nodejs. I have done with get request of select query. but now am trying the post request with insert query. But I can't pass my req.body.name into the following query

```
app.post('/ping', bodyparser.json(), function(req, res) {
    console.log("post enter");

    const query = "insert into student (name) values ("+req.body.name+") ";

    sql.query(connectionString, query, (err,rows) => {
        console.log(rows);
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
        else {
            return  res.send(rows);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: You should parametrising your query, not injecting the value.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
    app.post('/register',function(req,res){
          var users={
    "first_name":req.body.first_name,
    "last_name":req.body.last_name,
    "email":req.body.email,
    "password":req.body.password,
    "created":today,
    "modified":today
  }
  connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?',users, function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("error ocurred",error);
    res.send({
      "code":400,
      "failed":"error ocurred"
    })
  }else{
    console.log('The solution is: ', results);
    res.send({
      "code":200,
      "success":"user registered sucessfully"
        });
  }
        });
    });
```

Comment: am getting IError: [msnodesql] Invalid parameter(s) passed to function query or queryRaw.

Comment: I have done the post call with mysql as you said but in sql server I should do parameterized..